# How Do I Change The Background Color Around Python Tkinter ttk.OptionMenu Widget? (Mac)

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, optionmenu

I am trying to make a script that lets you choose a day, then displays the day you have chosen on the tkinter window.

But when i have tried to change the background of the entire window to black, i didn't find a way to change the background color around the `OptionMenu` widget that lets you pick a day to black also.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvrqN.png) is an example to what i mean (Mac).

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root= Tk()
root.geometry('200x300')
root.configure(bg= 'black')

def selected(event):
    Label(root, text= clicked.get(), bg= 'black').pack()
    clicked.set(options[0])

options= ['Pick A Day', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']

clicked= StringVar()
clicked.set(options[0])

drop= ttk.OptionMenu(root, clicked, *options, command= selected)
drop.pack(pady= 20)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

> i didn't find a way to change the background color around the
> OptionMenu widget that lets you pick a day to black

Add this before `select(event)` function.

```
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure("TMenubutton", background="black", foreground='white')

def selected(event):
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After the following line:

`drop = ttk.OptionMenu(root, clicked, *options, command= selected)`

You should add this:

```
drop.config(bg="black")
drop.pack(pady= 20)
```